# How to get the defined data-type of text field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fetch the **data-type="string"** using jQuery.  Below is the input field which I am using.

```
<tr>
     <td id="empName" style="display:none">Alex Philip</td>
     <td id="empDesig">Manager</td>
     <td><input type="text" class="input-5ea007b4ccbc8e4af01e2000 change-fun form-control" data- 
       employeename="Alex" **data-type="string"** name="Alex"></td>
    </tr>
```

On change, I am able to fetch the value of the field, but I need the data-type also.

```
var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");
var empHtml=currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();
var empActualValue=currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
```

I have used currentRow.find("td:eq(1)")..data.type; but getting undefined

Comment: You can get it like this : `currentRow.find("td:eq(2) input").attr("data-type")`

Comment: Thanks a lot Swati for the help..

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it should be

```
currentRow.find("td:eq(2) input").data("type");
```